# SQL query bug at android-"no executable code found ...."

Tags: android, sql

i would like help with finding what is wrong with my SQL query at my app.

```
//update pass in db
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

String query = " UPDATE " + Password.TABLE + " SET " + Password.KEY_NAME + "='" + newName + "'," +
               Password.KEY_URL + "='" + newUrl + "'," +
               Password.KEY_USER + "=" + newUser + Password.KEY_PASS + "=" + newPass+"'," + " WHERE " + Password.KEY_NAME + "='" + oldName + "' AND " +
               Password.KEY_URL + " = '" + oldUrl +  "';" ;

db.execSQL(query);
db.close(); //closing db connection
```

error: 
http://postimg.org/image/xp1kvn3k5/

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `,` right before your `WHERE`. Try:

```
String query = " UPDATE " + Password.TABLE + " SET " + Password.KEY_NAME + "='" + newName + "'," +
   Password.KEY_URL + "='" + newUrl + "'," +
   Password.KEY_USER + "=" + newUser + Password.KEY_PASS + "=" + newPass+"' " + " WHERE " + Password.KEY_NAME + "='" + oldName + "' AND " +
   Password.KEY_URL + " = '" + oldUrl +  "';" ;
```